# PHP - Double Recursive Multiplication

Tags: php, recursion, numbers, multiplication

Im creating a function to calculate prices for my business, but im stuck on one point

```
$cost = 5.4; 
$price = $cost + ($price*0.105) + ($price*0.1);
```

How i can do this math? It´s a recursive formula but i dont see the solution.. I tried to search but havent see the way to do it.

If someone can help me, thank you

Comment: What is your expected result for `$price` in this example?

Comment: $price should be 6.79 ... ($price*0.105) should be 0.713 and ($price*0.1) should be 0.679

Comment: And how do you get `6.79` ? please post the calculation with replacing the variables with the values you expect

Comment: what is the initial value of $price?!!

Comment: I use excel to do this math everyday.. now im putting it on my system. Im a 10y+ php programmer but im a little lost today =p

Comment: @Rizier123, i got the 6.79 in excel; $cost=5.4; $v1=0.713; (10,5% of price) $v2=0.679; (10% of price) $price=$cost+$v1+$v2 .. got the idea?

Comment: What is the value of `price` before you execute the statement?

Comment: 10.5% of the price is not 0.713. Its 0.567

Comment: It is 5.4... then you need to add more 10,5% and more 10%.

Comment: In excel, put this values on cells: A1=5.4, A2=A4*0.105, A3=A4*0.10, A4=SUM(A1:A3)

Comment: @IndraKumars, 10,5% is 0.713 because it should be 10,5% of price plus that 10,5% .. it´s 10,5% of the sum

Comment: Your excel formula itself is wrong. You are making a circular refrence

Comment: Lets simplify.. $price = 5.4 + (10% of final price) ... in this case, price will be 5.99 and that 10% (of 5,99) is 0.59.... So 5.4 + 0.59 = 5.99

Comment: Yes! I need a circular reference! The problem is i dont know how to do this in PHP.

Comment: In excel itself Value will not come... It shows #REF!

Comment: @IndraKumarS, here its working.. You have circular reference ON in excel? But the point is that.. how to resolve a circular reference formula on php

Comment: Clarify it. $price= 5.4 +(10 % of 5.4).... will it not be 5.94 ?

Comment: In excel, you will have this values: A1 = 5.4 // A2 = 0.713 (A4*0.105) // A3 = 0.679 (A4*0.1) // A4 = 6.79 (A1+A2+A3)

Comment: @IndraKumarS, no $price=5.4+(10%of price) => $price=5.4+(10% of price  with the 10%)... in this example price will be = 6.00 and 10% (of 6.0) will be 0.6 .... so 5.4+0.6 = 6.0 ... and the 0.6 is 10% of 6.00 ... Got it ? Sorry if confuse you

Comment: price will be = 6.00 and 10% will be 0.6 .... 5.4+0.6 = 6.0 ?????????? why 5.4+0.6 and why not 6+0.6?

Comment: Thats the formula.. its for taxes of the price..

Comment: Taxes is 10% of final price... $finalprice = $cost(5.4) + $tax(10% of finalprice).

Comment: If i have a final price of 6.00, i will pay 10% of taxes (0.6)... got ?

Comment: Leave the numbers Tell me the logic. $cost+$tax=$finalPrice Right?......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't follow the entire discussion in the comments but if that relationship is correct then it's just a simple math equation:

```
$cost = 5.4;
$price = $cost + ($price*0.105) + ($price*0.1);
```

Move all the term that contain `$price` on the left hand side:

```
$price - 0.105 * $price - 0.1 * $price = $cost
```

Do the math on the left hand side:

```
$price * (1 - 0.105 - 0.1) = $cost
0.795 * $price = $cost
```

Divide both sides by `0.795` and that's all:

```
$price = $cost / 0.795;
```

Now

```
echo($price);
```

displays:

```
6.7924528301887
```

that rounded on two digits is `6.79`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the name of this calculation.. Its markup

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/percntof2.htm

Thankz everyone!